# Querying Local Group Policy using VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi, gpo

Using VBscript, what is the best way to query the 'User Rights Assignment' in Local Group Polices.
Such as getting the groups and users under 'Deny log on as a service'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to access this area of windows through VBS (at least AFAIK). But you might export the current privileges through "secedit /export" to a file and then analyze this file.